# Jquery stopImediatePropagation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three events handlers , mouseenter,mouseleave,and click
If the user clicks on "li" i want stop the event propagation in order to not execute the mouseleave handler
Here's my code:

```
$('.list ul li').mouseenter(function()
    {
        $(this).addClass('listItemSelected');
    });   
    $('.list ul li').mouseleave(function()
    {
        $(this).removeClass('listItemSelected');
    });
    $('.list ul li').click(function(b)
    {
        b.stopImmediatePropagation();   
        $('.list ul').removeClass('listItemSelected');
        $(this).addClass('listItemSelected');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update

```
$('.list ul li').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.list ul').removeClass('listItemSelected');
    // first remove from the rest of the list items then add to clicked
    $('.list ul li').removeClass('listItemClicked');
    $(this).addClass('listItemClicked');
});
```

Make listItemSelected the same as listItemClicked

Comment: the problem is that the class listItemSelected is dynamically created,

Comment: I don't know what you mean, why do you need to add the class on hover? is it for styling or other purposes?

Comment: styling, i change the background color, but the color is not fixed, is dinamically take from a database

Comment: hmmmm in that case change the class name for click but the css for the click class is the same as the one for the hover. This way you can avoid adding/removing the event handlers which will become taxing

Comment: thanks Huangism , finally i use your solution, the another one bring me into some issues.